# Native query with parameters - Escaping double quotes in a text value

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, nativequery

I have a JPA postgres native query like below (I simplified it quite a bit) :

```
WITH jdc (page, poste, segment_data_type, value) AS ( 
VALUES 
   ('2033C', 'MA', 'MOA', '912.66'),
   ('2033C', 'KA', 'FTX', 'SCREEN SIZE 11"'),
   ('2033C', 'GF', 'MOA', '4763.89')
),

num_pages(nom, numero) AS ( 
  VALUES    
    ('2058C', 11),
    ('2035A', 1),
    ('2035B', 2) 
) 

SELECT * FROM e_zeph_tzj tr 
JOIN jdc ON jdc.poste = tr.tzj_poste_jdc 
JOIN num_pages ON num_pages.nom = tr.tzj_page_zephir
WHERE tr.tzj_liasse = :param
```

Whenever I have a value with a double quote in the CTE:

> ```
> ('2033C', 'KA', 'FTX', 'SCREEN SIZE 11" ')
> ```

with the usual parameter setting:

```
Query query = em.createNativeQuery(queryStr);
query.setParameter("param", some_value);
```

I get an IllegalArgementException :

> Parameter with that name [param] did not exist

I have tried :

```
value = value.replace("\"", "\\\"");
```

resulting in the following string :

```
('2033C', 'KA', 'FTX', 'SCREEN SIZE 11\" ')
```

which sadly does not change the outcome when setting the parameter.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Environment :

- Database : postgres 9.4
- JDK : 1.8 - 13

Thanks

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe: no, the placeholder in JDBC is `?`, but JPA uses the `:xxxx` syntax for placeholders

Comment: @Laurenz Albe Sorry, my bad. It's a JPA native query. I have edited the question.

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Ah, yes, of course, sorry. Since that error message comes from neither PostgreSQL nor the JDBC driver, it probably comes from JPA. It feels like an SQL injection bug to me, but I concur that with out a reproducible example it is hard to say for sure.

Answer (score 0):

The error 'Parameter with that name [param] does not exist', obviously refers to the `"param"` in `query.setParameter("param", some_value);` and has absolutely nothing whatsoever to do with the `value` part. As a consequence, messing with the `value` part is going to do nothing at all to fix this problem.

The `"param"` part is the actual name of an actual parameter. Nothing in your query has that name.

Put `":param"` somewhere in a query, such as: `SELECT * FROM foo WHERE name = :param`, then you have a parameter you can set with `query.setParameter("param", some_value);`.

More generally if you aren't going to use hibernate/JPA like it wants to be used, and you just want to do native queries, you're using the wrong tool for the job. Try [JDBI](http://www.jdbi.org/) or JOOQ.

Comment: the :param is right there at the end of the main query :)
Removing the special characters from the value allows for a normal execution of the code. Other special characters like > or < messed the execution in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do this to trim the double quotes, for a postgres backed JPA query.

like so : `trim( both '\"' from ds.dataId)` => this will trim the double quotes (") from the resulting string at both the ends.

```
 @Query(value = "select new com.api.models.ClassNameStatus("+
            "cast( trim( both '\"' from ds.dataId) as java.lang.String),cast( trim ( both '\"' from ds.comp) as java.lang.String)," +
            "cast( trim (both '\"' from ds.dc) as java.lang.String),cast( trim ( both '\"' from be.custUrl) as java.lang.String)" +
            ",cast( trim ( both '\"' from be.username) as java.lang.String),cast( trim ( both '\"' from tr.tits) as java.lang.String)" +
            ",cast(trim ( both '\"' from tr.bussy) as java.lang.String))  \n" +
            "from AssGuardingEntity )
```